# Display Toast : editText + 10

Tags: java, android

Hi Guys I created a EditText named as enter and a Textview named as display and a button named as convert and I want when I press button I get the value of edtitext + 10 get it? I trued this in the pic but am getting the value of edit text and 10 beside it but not added to it. 
I tried this http://s10.postimg.org/4fk6thx7t/IMG_20150525_160900.jpg

Comment: You have to parse that string value into Integer then add 10 .

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),(Integer.valueOf(str)+10)+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert your edit text value to integer add then add it
like

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(enter.getText.toString());
int res = i+10;
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(res), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A string value can't be added to integer value, so you need to convert the string value to integer value after that add the value with 10.
 try this code:-

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),(Integer.valueOf(str)+10)+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before parse to integer just check that value must not be null

```
String value = enter.getText.toString();
```

Now check

```
if(!value.equals("")){

int i = Integer.parseInt(value);
int res = i+10;
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(res), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only concation of EditText Value With 10 than try following code

```
string val= enter.getText.toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),val+10,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and if you want to add editText Value with 10 than try folloing code

```
int valueFromEditText = Integer.parseInt(enter.getText.toString());
int ans = valueFromEditText+10;
Toast.makeText(this, ans, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  very simple

  try input_type= "decimal" in your xml
  Integer sum = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
  sum = sum+10;
  Toast.makeText(context,"your edittext + 10 ="+sum,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This is also alternate answer